# Error inserting data in Mysql fom android:Android Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() in AsyncTask

Tags: android, mysql

I am simply trying to insert data into mysql database from android activity on Click of a button.But i am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.blood.bloodconnect.register$1$1.run(register.java:57)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:152)
```

at com.blood.bloodconnect.register$1$1.run(register.java:57)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

register.java:

```
public class register extends Activity
{

EditText name,address,bg,ph,email,age;
Button register;


private ProgressDialog pDialog;
int flag=0;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static String url = "http://192.168.1.6/phpfiles/register.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etname);
    age=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etage);
    address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etadd);
    bg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etbg);
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etemail);
    ph=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etphone);


    register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnreg);

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view){

         new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  new loginAccess().execute();                  }
          }).start();

        }
    });

 } 

  class loginAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(register.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        String n=name.getText().toString();
        String a=age.getText().toString();
        String add=address.getText().toString();
        String e=email.getText().toString();
        String phone=ph.getText().toString();
        String bloodgroup=bg.getText().toString();


        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", n));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", a));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address",add));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", e));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneno",phone));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bloogroup",bloodgroup));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params);

        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1)
            {
                flag=0;
                //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),search.class);
                /*i.putExtra("mobile_number",number);
                i.putExtra("password",pwd);*/
                //startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            else
            {
                // failed to Sign in
               flag=1;
            }
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        /*if(flag==1)
            Toast.makeText(register.this,"Please Enter Correct informations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

*/
        }

```
  }


}
```

php file:

```
<?php

 // array for JSON response
 $response = array();

// check for required fields

if (isset($_POST['name'])) 
{  
$phone = $_POST['phoneno'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];

$email = $_POST['email'];  
$bloodgroup = $_POST['bloodgroup'];  
$address = $_POST['address'];  

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("Insert into bloodtb(name,age,address,email,phone,bloodgroup) values('$name','$age','$address','$email','$phone','$bloodgroup')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
  } else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I have seen other stackoverflow answers related to this type of error but it doesnt work still..Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `new Thread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { new loginAccess().execute(); } }).start();`

And replace with

`new loginAccess().execute();`

Remember an `AsyncTask` already does it's work off the main thread.

Comment: oh yes thanks...atleast now it is not force closing.But still now the data is not being inserted in the database..please help.

Comment: Now i dont get any error in my log cat but my data is not being inserted in the mysql database..Please help me solve this problem.